# Measurement of station grounding resistance and test electrodes

Tags: grounding, electrode

This is a pure electrical engineering question.

I have seen a request for embedding test electrodes and connect them by "disconnectable" joints to a few earthing bars inside a station building, in order to later test resistance to earth (or grounding resistance) of the station itself.

Since it is known that for a large station with a significant earth grid surface and vertical electrodes, the distance of removable test electrodes is recommended to be much larger than the maximum grid extension (IEEE Std. 80, Fall-of-Potential method), how embedded test electrodes in between grounding electrodes and close to the grid can serve the purpose? they will be unavoidably strongly coupled to the grounding system subject to measurement, that is in general a thing to avoid for meaningful and accurate results.

Do you have ref to standards, guidelines, past experience, good ideas?

Thank you fellows.

Comment: Usually you would need to take a course with your own (and approved) instrument with calibration document. It is extremely important that electrician that performs grounding measurements knows how the instrument works and all procedures to get a valid measurement.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clearly expressed. The problem is not dealt with by usual courses: if you look into manuals of Megger, Fluke, etc. they propose -- correctly -- fall-of-potential method, clamp method, etc. In the present case there is a specific requirement for a test electrode that cannot comply with such methods (BS 7430, IEEE Std. 80 and 81). The question is: have you ever seen or heard of a method or practice using test electrodes for large station earthing systems located inside the station itself, not complying with the required separation distance?